# Scrapyd pause/continue job

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

Looks like there is no legal way to pause/continue crawling with Scrapyd, as it was with Scrapy itself (scrapy crawl spider -s JOBDIR=jobdir/spider-1). 
The only resolution i've found was here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scrapyusers/2VjEBEbOo7s/MSH4GJc2B0sJ

but i haven't understand the idea.

So is it possible to pause/continue job with Scrapyd?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

The idea is following:

When you run your spider from `cmd` you can paste additional    an argument, for example: `scrapy crawl myspider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1`

When you use `Scrapyd` in endpoint `schedule.json` you can also paste some settings. If you are using `scrapyd-client` this will look like this:

```
s = {'JOBDIR': 'crawls/somespider-1'}
job = api.schedule(project_name, spider_name, settings=s)
```

After it, you can cancel a job. Next time, when you will run the same job - scrapyd resume previous work

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand where to write this options. If i run crawler with: (curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=my-parsers -d spider=my_spider) where should i paste your code?

Comment: In this case, you can make a call so: `curl localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=my-parsers -d spider=my_spider -d settings=JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work either. When i resume such job with: `curl localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=my-parsers -d spider=my_spider -d settings=JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1 jobid=3123asds5f34141asdfesw324` the new parse start from the beginning, only  a log is the same